# Why isn't my custom fonts loaded onto React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am trying to use a custom font for my project. I have all variations of 'Roboto' saved into my assets folder.

My react-native config

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ["./assets/fonts/"]
};
```

My Theme page which exports the custom fonts

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export const FONTS = {
largeTitle: { fontFamily: "Roboto-regular", fontSize: SIZES.largeTitle, lineHeight: 55 },
h1: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Black", fontSize: SIZES.h1, lineHeight: 36 },
h2: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", fontSize: SIZES.h2, lineHeight: 30 },
}

const appTheme = { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS };

export default appTheme;
```

And on my Home Page I am trying to use the font.

```
import React from "react"
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, FlatList } from "react- 
native"
import { COLORS, SIZES, icons, images, FONTS } from '../constants'

function renderMainCategories(){
    return (

    <View style={{ padding:SIZES.padding * 2 }}>
        <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h1 }}>Main</Text>
        <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h1 }}>Categories</Text>
    </View>

)}
```

As you can see in the style={{ ...FONTS.h1 }} I feel like I've done everything right but for some reason it gives me an error while trying to use the font.

It gives me this error ---

fontFamily "Roboto-Black" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

I've tried to find Font.loadAsync and also tried to add it to the parent component but it doesn't work! And I've tried npx react-native link! I'd really appreciate someone advice and not just a link to a page thanks!

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo you can try to use `useFonts` : https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this link properly, you should be able to solve the problem:
https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: That was the first link I tried but didnt work.